# how to change background image of Tapku calendar

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, calendar, tapku

[image: i am attaching tapku calendar image below]!

I tried with below code.But the image is not setted.

```
TKCalendarMonthView *calendar = [[TKCalendarMonthView alloc] init];

calendar.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fishimage.png"]];
```

"Thanks in Advance"

Comment: Yo dude, whats the question. And whats Tapku?

Comment: @RohanKapur Hover over the "tapku" tag.

Comment: @H2CO3 Ha, I see, silly me.

Comment: You're missing the basics. I suppose that it inherits from UIView, you have to add it as subview of your view controller's view.

Comment: The thing is that this view uses CoreGraphics for drawing. It won't by any means respect the set background color since it's misimplemented and it doesn't call `[super drawRect:rect];` - blame it on the author of this library.

Comment: i add calender as subview to view controller but background image is not setting.

Comment: @Vidhyanand Bothered to read my previous comment?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NO It is not possible to change whole image of Tapku calendar because it is collection of  (may be) button/view which contain dates number. But  you can change **image of change month Arrow** by following method of `UIImage+TKCategory.m` class

```
+ (UIImage*) imageNamedTK:(NSString*)str{

    CGFloat s = 1.0f;
    if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)]){
        s = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
    }

    //NSString *path = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@.png",str,s > 1 ? @"@2x":@""];
    return [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.jpg"]CGImage] scale:s orientation:UIImageOrientationUp]; // put here specific image name for display !

}
```

Answer (score 3):

No Need to change any coding just replace image

goto TapkuLibrary.bundle --> Images --> calendar AND
Rplace your image with "Month Calendar Date Tile.png"

**OR**

Change code in TKCalendarMonthView.m

`tileImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"fishimage.png"];`

with

```
tileImage = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:TKBUNDLE(@"calendar/Month Calendar Date Tile.png")];
```